# Unable to edit IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have the following view:

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resources.Edit;
}

<h2>@Resources.EditRole</h2>

@Html.ActionLink(Resources.ListRoles, "Index") | @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ManageUserRoles, "ManageUserRoles")
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="editRoleForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Role", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>@Resources.Role</h4>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have the following two methods in my `RoleController`:

```
        //
        // GET: /Role/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string Role)
        {
            var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(Role, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(thisRole);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Role/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Id.Equals(collection["Id"])).FirstOrDefault();
                thisRole.Name = collection["Name"];
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Originally, I was trying to use this method instead of the second one:

```
    //
    // POST: /Role/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(IdentityRole Name)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Entry(Name).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But I never got it to work because the `Name` parameter was always `null` -which I still don't know why it happened, so if someone can explain it to me that'll be greatly appreciated.

I wrote then the other method since I saw the use of `FormCollection` in another example (to create roles) and it seems to work fine, at least it contains the information I need when I debug it. My issue is that although `collection["id"]` has the right Id for the Role I'm trying to edit, `context.Roles` is completely empty. This makes no sense to me given that when the first method is called (loading the View for the first time), this line

`var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(Role, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();`

returns the selected role (out of the several that exist and that I can see when I add to watch `context.Roles`). However, after the view is loaded, the textbox edited and the second method in the controller gets called, `context.Roles` has nothing in it. Why?

Comment: Your Edit POST should bind to an IdentityRole -- Edit(IdentityRole role)...  The role object should then have the Id and Name populated from your view. If that's not happening use a tool like fiddler or chrome developer tools to inspect.

Comment: I think the reason "Name" was always null in your second snippet was that it was the same as the name as a property in the object.  Try using a different identifier, say, "roleName" instead of "Name".

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use the already built in `[Authorize(Roles="RoleType")]` filter.

You then have your regular User model and Account controller so you can then authorize users. Once you have authorised them you can set them to a specific role.

E.g. user story: only admins can access action result x

```
[Authorize(User="Admin")]
Public ActionResult X(){
...
}
```

That way you simply assign user roles in the model creation.

E.g.

```
Public Class UserModel
{
int id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
string Role {get;set;}
.....
}
```

Now only users that have been authorised AND are of Role type "Admin" will be able to access that controller.

If you want to edit their role you can do a simple edit user action method

e.g.

```
    [Post]
    public actionresult edituser(int? id)
    {
    if (id == null)
       {
     return HttpNotFound();
       }

       using (var db = new UserContext())
    {
     UserModel editUser = db.UserModel.Find(id);
     if (editUser == null)
    {
    return HttpNotFound();
    }

db.User(editModel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
}
RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}
```

Now any user that is NOT of Role type "Admin" will not be able to access that screen. They will receive a 404 error.

Comment: I think he's trying to edit the IdentityRole, not assign or authorize users. Could be wrong.

Comment: :( bad misunderstanding  (if thats the case).